# Non-Linear Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

How can I find Nth term for this recurrence relation

```
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + F(n-1)*F(n-2)
```

I have to find Nth term for this recurrence relation modulo `10^9+7`.

I know how to find Nth term for linear recurrence relations but unable to proceed for this.

```
1<=N<=10^9
```

F(0) and F(1) are provided as an input.

Comment: Read `matrix exponentiation`

Comment: You must wnat the value mod X, right?

Comment: Are you sure the upper bound on `N` is `10^9` and you need the whole number, not just it's value modulo something?

Comment: @vish4071 Can you tell me how can I make the matrix for it? i know about matrix exponentiation method to solve linear recurrence relations.

Comment: I just need value mod X. not the original value. I'll update my question.

Comment: @MarkSamuel Is `X` given? How large is it?

Comment: I'll try and make the matrix and post it as answer. Wait a while.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 X is `10^9+7`

Comment: Have you tried to see whether or not a pattern starts to form for that modulo?

Comment: @IVlad F(0) & F(1) are variable inputs, so I didn't try searching for any pattern, since it will change according to the value provided.

Comment: @IVlad Given that `10^9 + 7` is large and prime, initial values are provided as input and the relation is non-linear, it's improbable.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but for `F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1`, the answer is `F(n) = 2**fibonacci(n) - 1`.

Comment: this question is from a live contest on hackerearth. plz remove this.

Answer (score 12):

There's a trick. Let `G(n) = F(n) + 1`. The equation

```
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + F(n-1)*F(n-2)
```

becomes

```
G(n) - 1 = G(n-1) - 1 + G(n-2) - 1 + (G(n-1) - 1) * (G(n-2) - 1)
         = G(n-1) - 1 + G(n-2) - 1 + G(n-1)*G(n-2) - G(n-1) - G(n-2) + 1
         = G(n-1)*G(n-2) - 1,
```

so adding `1` to both sides,

```
G(n) = G(n-1)*G(n-2).
```

This is the multiplicative equivalent of the familiar Fibonacci recurrence. The solution is

```
G(n) = G(0)^Fib(n-1) * G(1)^Fib(n),
```

by analogy with the theory of linear recurrences (where `Fib(-1) = 1` and `Fib(0) = 0` and `Fib(1) = 1`), since

```
G(n-1)*G(n-2) = G(0)^Fib(n-2) * G(1)^Fib(n-1)
              * G(0)^Fib(n-3) * G(1)^Fib(n-2)
              = G(0)^Fib(n-1) * G(1)^Fib(n)
              = G(n).
```

Hence,

```
F(n) = (F(0)+1)^Fib(n-1) * (F(1)+1)^Fib(n) - 1,
```

doing the `Fib` computations via the matrix power method mod `p-1` per [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) and the exponentiation mod `p`.

Comment: Nice. So my comment about `2**fibo(n)-1` was very close :).

Comment: For `F(0)=1` & `F(1)=2` and for n>45, the formula is giving wrong answers. I tested it against the memorization solution which works fine for cases where n<1000000. Any idea why this behaviour because the formula is giving correct answers for all n less than 45.

Comment: @MarkSamuel 45 is the least n such that Fib(n) > 10^9+7. Are you using the correct modulus, p-1, for the Fib computations?