# Extension of Fast Doubling Method

Tags: math

`N`th term of sequence in which

```
F(N) = F(N-1) + F(N-2) + F(N-1)×F(N-2)
```

mod any big no. lets say `10^9+7`.. `F(0)=a` and `F(1)=b` is also given.

I am trying Fast Doubling Method but I am not able to get the matrix. How to efficiently compute except obvious O(n) algorithm

Comment: Just search a bit - your classmates asked this question last day.

Comment: @Mbo: Please add next time a link, I searched for the duplicates before answering and found none. Here are some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720425/non-linear-recurrence-relation, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742690/3088138. Apparently, this is a question from a programming contest on hackerearth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-Linear Recurrence Relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720425/non-linear-recurrence-relation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `G[n]=log(1+F[n])` to find

```
G[n] = G[n-1] + G[n-2]
```

This is the Fibonacci recursion that has the general solution

```
G[n] = Fib[n-1]*G[0] + Fib[n]*G[1]
```

which translates to

```
1+F[n] = (1+F[0])^Fib[n-1] * (1+F[1])^Fib[n]
```

where `Fib` is the Fibonacci sequence that has values `1,0,1` for indices `n=-1,0,1`.

Now apply the usual techniques for the Fibonacci sequence.